# Difference between JQuery v1.10.2 and 1.12.0

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a template which uses JQuery v1.10.2 and want to upgrade it.

Can I use 1.12.0 instead of it?

**EDIT:** I'm only using the template, not creating it.

Comment: Yes you can. There are no/very few breaking changes in the 1.x branch from 1.10 up

Comment: hi. I'm not creating the template, just modifying as I need. so I won't do this upgrade if it's possible to become any errors. I edited the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgrading [from 1.10 to 1.11](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/01/24/jquery-1-11-and-2-1-released/) was said not to break code. And upgrading [from 1.11 to 1.12](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/08/jquery-2-2-and-1-12-released/) was also said not to break code.

Therefore, I would say **you don't run any risk upgrading from 1.10 to 1.12**. However, you should always run some tests before deploying code to production after upgrading jQuery (or any other library you use).

Comment: Note: If a software product is using [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), only major versions should be allowed to make breaking changes. So for example going from jQuery 1.x.x to jQuery 2.x.x could introduce breaking changes, going from 1.1.0 to 1.2.0 **shouldn't**, if they're following semantic versioning.

Comment: You are totally right @leroydev. However, as the jQuery devs say themselves in the linked blog posts, they can mistakes too and introduce unexpected breaking changes, which is why testing is a responsible thing to do.